# Save HTML canvas to image won't work some how

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I need some help:

I am trying to save an image from my html canvas. I did get it to work, but when i click the button "Save", i only get de coloured background i've generated. I am using images in my canvas (png images), wich somehow seem to dissapear when i try to save the canvas to a file.

Weird thing is: when i right-mouse click, and choose "save image", it seems to work fine! Is there something i should keep in my in my coding, or is this just not possible somehow?

Ive looked for a solution on the internet but didn't come across something that worked for me.. And i am aalso kind off new to the html canvas. Any kiond of help would be very appreciated!

the code:

```
<style>
  #buttonRows{width:100%; height:200px;float:left;background-color:#666;}
  #buttonRow_01{width:100%; height:40px; border-top:1px solid #333; float:left;margin-top:10px;}
  #buttonRow_02{width:100%; height:40px; border-top:1px solid #333; float:left;margin-top:10px;}
  #label{padding:10px;float:left;height:50px;}
  #button{width:300px;height:50px; background-color:#CCC;border:none;cursor:pointer;}
  #img_container{ width:500px; margin:20px; border:5px solid #000;}
  #img_container img{ width:100%;height:auto}
</style>

<div id="buttonRows">
  <input id="button" type="button" value="Update button" onclick="refresh();" />
  <div id="buttonRow_01">
    <div id="label">Achtergrondkleur:</div>
    <input type="textbox" value="FF0000" id="colorInput" class="color" onchange="refresh();"/>
  </div>

  <div id="buttonRow_02">
    <div id="label">Laag 1:</div>
    <input type="range" value="50" id="opacitySlider"/>
    <select id="blendSelect" >
      <option value="screen">screen</option>
      <option value="multiply">multiply</option>
      <option value="source-over">none</option>
    </select>
    <select id="verbandSelect" >
      <option value="bs_standaart_cropped.png">standaart</option>
      <option value="bs_wild_cropped.png">wild</option>
    </select>
  </div>

</div>

 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1280" height="720" ></canvas>
<img id="canvasImg" src="" />

 <script>
   function refresh(){  
     var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
     var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
     context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     context.globalAlpha = 1;
     context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";

     var CI = document.getElementById('colorInput');

     var OS = document.getElementById('opacitySlider');
     var BS = document.getElementById('blendSelect');
     var VS = document.getElementById('verbandSelect');

      // draw blue rectangle
      context.beginPath();
      context.rect(0, 0, 1280, 720);
      context.fillStyle = '#' + CI.value;
      context.fill();

     // draw transparent red circle
      context.globalAlpha = OS.value/100;
      context.globalCompositeOperation = BS.value;
      var image = new Image();
      image.src =  "http://www.joey-cooijmans.nl/templates/JC-main/images/steenconf/" + VS.value;
      image.fillStyle="#00ff00";
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


   }

   refresh();

</script>
```

Comment: You could add your code to the post, so we would know what are you talking about.

Comment: Unfortunately, without posting your code- this question is too broad to answer...  Post code so we can help!

Comment: Oh right, sorry i forgot that! (My first post on the site :P)

Comment: image does not have a fillStyle (`image.fillStyle="#00ff00";`), also, you are missing an onload handler for the image. If your painted image doesn't comply to CORS requirement your canvas becomes "tainted" and won't allow you to extract it as an image. What does the console say?

Comment: I've removed the (image.fillStyle="#00ff00";), and i'll try the missing handler. The console says the following: Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported. I don't get it... i'll try the onload handler first

Comment: Allright people! I found a solution myself: It was about the path of the image. I changed the path to an relative path, and now ik works like a charm! thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

`canvas.toDataURL('image/png')` to turn the canvas into a base64 string which then you set the `href` of the download button and use the `download` attribute to do the file download. Note that the `download` attribute is not supported in all [browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) so the file will just open in a new tab with `_blank` as a fallback.

HTML

```
<a href id="save" download="canvas.png" target="_blank">save</a>
```

JavaScript

```
var saveButton = document.getElementById('save');
save.onclick = function(e) {
   var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
   save.href = dataUrl;
};
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/moogs/6z2fx7xc/2/**

Comment: Thanks for your response, i appreciate it! I tried the script you sent me, and it does make a downlaodable image, but it appears to be a corrupted file. It wont open unforunately :(